# My breakpoint is not being hit when a string variable contain the char "$"

Tags: c#

In my code, I'm adding a breakpoint with the condition `resxKey==@"$this.Text"`
at line `resxKey = d.Key.ToString();` (see below).

When I add this breakpoint without any conditions and manually detect the value, the variable `resxKey` equals `"$this.Text"`. However, if I add the condition `resxKey==@"$this.Text"`, the line will never be hit.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
 resxReader = new ResXResourceReader(resxPathName);
 string resxKey = "";
 string resxValue = "";
 foreach (DictionaryEntry d in resxReader)
                {
                    int i;

                    resxKey = d.Key.ToString();             // I add a breakpoint at this line 
                }                                        //with condtion resxKey==@"$this.Text"
```

Comment: Where are the condition and break point?

Answer (score 1):

You should set the breakpoint at the statement *after* `resxKey = d.Key.ToString();`.

If you set the breakpoint at that statement, it will indeed never be hit because `resxKey` is not yet assigned the value of `d.Key.ToString()`.

Maybe the best workaround would be to leave the breakpoint there but change its condition to `d.Key.ToString() == "$this.Text"`.